# Spelling of feminine name "Майя" in Ukrainian

Tags: spelling, власні-назви

Kindly advise if there is an explanation of such spelling of the feminine name **Майя** in Ukrainian (with `й`) with consequent specific declension rules?

I assume it should not be compared with **Рая** **Тая**, due to the two being abridged forms from *Раїса*, *Таїса*, but why, for instance, **Зоя** - without `й`?

- [МАЙЯ](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%CC%C0%C9%DF)
- [ЗОЯ](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%C7%CE%DF&x=32&y=7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it is prescribed to be written in this way (*Майя*), because it descends from the Ancient Greek name *Μαϊα* (meaning [goddess Maia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maia_(mythology)) and "mother"), which is **pronounced as /maja/ ⟨mah-yah⟩ itself**.

While *Зоя* also has Greek origin (from *[ζωή](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B6%CF%89%CE%AE#Greek)* — "life"), it is pronounced by Greeks themselves as /zoˈi/ (not as /zoja/) and originally spelled in Old Church Slavonic as *Зоис* /zoˈis/. Therefore the final spelling *Зоя* appears to be a result of **posterior Slavic transformation** of the word, not of original pronunciation transcription.

The same is true for *Рая*, *Тая* — these are Slavic short-hands for *Раїса*, *Таїсія*. Origins of *Раїса* and *Таїсія* don't even matter. The obvious fact — that ending *-я* was **created by Slavs** — matters.

---

Update: English Wikipedia proposes other etymologies for [given name *Maya*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_(given_name)): from Hindu word *māyā* ("illusion"), name *Māyā*, Hebrew name *מאיה* (Maya, short of *ma'ayan* "spring"/"brook"), Maya people (in Mesoamerica), Japanese name *Mayako/Mayaka*, mountain *Maya*, Māori name *Maia* ("palm tree"), etc. What is common in all these etymologies, is that an original pronunciation in all these cases is /maja/ ⟨mah-yah⟩ (or starts with /maja…/).

On the other hand, corresponding Russian name can be spelled as both *Майя* (more often) and *Мая* (rare). [Russian etymologies](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%8F_(%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F)) include the Greek version (as primary) and descending from the Russian month name *май* (*May*; Ukrainian *травень*). The latter etymology seems to be really valid reasoning for spelling it as *Мая* (though *май* descends from *Μαϊα* itself (through *Maius* and *May*), a name owner can always say "my name is from *май*, not directly from *Μαϊα*").

---

TL;DR: Not the origin itself mostly matters, but the fact whether the ending *-я* was added by Slavs **during the transcription/transliteration** (to resemble the original pronunciation/writing) or **during the later transformations**. (Although the origin may matter too, because transcription/transliteration rules may depend on origin.)

Comment: Many thanks for your good answer! As for *"Russian etymology"* to explain the origin of **Maya** form **May**  it looks very much like so called [**"folk (or false) etymology'**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F), doesn't it?

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, I think, in the case of given names, we can't apply such terms as "folk/false etymology" (or "improper spelling"). Just because "it's a my child and I named him/her *A* (not *B*) in the name of *C* (not *D*)". Folk/false etymology (and improper spelling) are for common nouns; or for proper nouns that exist for centuries (those who created them are already dead); or, sometimes, for blindly-reused proper nouns. But if, say, **I** named something explicitly *X* because of specifically *Y*, you can't call it false etymology/spelling, because **I** named it.

Comment: and here goes a bright example, when parents give a name **"Альона"** (in Ukrainian by transliteration from Russian *"Алёна"*) to a girl and not to be blamed in stupidity explain that **"Альона"** came from **"Альо"**. Just a joke :)

Answer (score -1):

It can be hard to get used to this rules of declension (it's hard to understand even for Ukrainians) >> [Відміни](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm)
There are rules of dividing word by it's ending and how it's declension.
This word belongs to I soft group. Hope I helped you

So according to that rules, these names belong to the same declension and group and subgroup - they ended with the same letter - "я". It doesn't matter from what word they were created at this point. Letter at the end matters only. And according to that they share declension rules

Comment: Welcome to Ukrainian Language.SE! Unfortunately, this post only hints to possible answer(s), but it does not actually answer the question. This can be a comment, however. Or please consider [edit] 'ing it to get closer to answering the question. Also, check [this Meta post](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5/) to see our quality standards.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but again, this does not seem to constitute an answer. Please re-read the question; the OP is not asking about the declension rules/groups; instead, they want to know why the seemingly similar proper names have different spelling of its **roots**. Namely, with or without the `й`.

Comment: @bytebuster, this answerer was deceived by tags: [tag:declension], [tag:відмінювання] — I removed them.

Comment: @Sasha the very question of mine includes *"with consequent specific declension rules"*, thus relevant tags have been used.